# Integrating Thomae's function, with a twist

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, riemann-integration

To start, this isn't *really* Thomae's function, because the interesting bit occurs when the argument is rational. But I couldn't think of any more closely-related function, and Thomae's was close enough.

Anyway, **my question:**

Let $- \infty < a,b < \infty$ be real numbers and say:
$$
  T(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   t(x) & \text{if $x$ is irrational.} \\
  \infty & \text{if $x$ is rational.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Where $t(x)$ is a continuous real-valued function. Then, is $\int_a^bT(x)dx$ defined?

**My thoughts:** I think this question depends on whether or not we can say $T(x)$ 
'equals' infinity at rational $x$ in which case we have some $\infty \times0$ wibble-wobble going on, or we must instead say $T(x)=k$ at rational $x$ and the integral in question becomes $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_a^bT(x)dx$ which, because the rationals are of density $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, reduces to $\int_a^bt(x)dx$, which is certainly defined.

Comment: The Riemann integral can't be defined because the function is not bounded, right? But the Lebesgue integral is well defined, and is as stated because there we have that the rationals can be discarded due to the rationals being of measure zero.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I'm not well-versed in Lebesgue integration, I just know that because the rationals are of measure zero, we can consider the integral to be 0 * (rational part) + 1*(irrational part), or at least that is how I can to know it. But, if the rational part 'is equal to infinity,' then we have some 0*infinity shenanigans; but is that 0*(rational part) what is really going on, are can we truly discard it and not even worry about multiplication by zero or 'infinity'?

Comment: To explain what is going on, I need you to know the definition of the Lebesgue integral for an arbitrary. Do you know it? Elsewise I shall introduce it in any answer I attempt.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am not 100% sure what you mean, but chances are I do need an explanation, so I’d go with: you should introduce it.

Comment: I am not able to give an answer that satisfies me, I am really sorry. All I can say is that since the rationals are of measure zero, the above function is "equal almost everywhere" to the continuous function $t(x)$ on $[a,b]$ so their integrals are the same. Unless the infiniteness comes onto a set of non-zero measure, the integral will remain finite